# Pin to set lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens

My phone recently forgot what my correct pattern to unlock the lockscreen. But when I reset the lock screen to swipe, now I can't change it to anything else because it asks for a pin to change it from swipe. I only ever set a backup pin for the pattern, and it isn't accepting that pin. How can I add security to my lockscreen again?

EDIT: Galaxy S5, Android 6.0.1

Comment: Mention the device and android version by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've resolved by this point, but for anyone else that comes across this issue:

I just ran into the same issue.  I managed to resolve it by going to https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager and used the lock option to set a different password.  Then I was able to go into lock screen settings and change to pin/pattern/ect as normal.